# Ubuntu DNS not working after installing a Bind Container

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-109-generic x86_64) server with Docker installed.  I created a Bind9 container however it would fail to start.  Turned out this was because the resolver service on Ubuntu was running and taking control of port 53.

So I killed the resolver service and then the Bind9 container would start.

Problem I have now is that Ubuntu host O\S won't resolve any DNS names.  I edited /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml to use external DNS servers but still nothing.

YAML file contents:

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s4:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.98/24
      - 192.168.0.99/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
  version: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The systemd-resolved listens on port `53` of `127.0.0.53`. It is this process that gets configured to use external resolvers, or not.

As your container refused to start until you killed the system resolver, I can only guess it was trying to listen on port `53` on the wildcard `0.0.0.0` address, which would be the default behavior.

The straightforward fix for this would be to change the way you start your Bind9 container so that it listens on only a specific IP address.

As pointed out in the comments, running bind on loopback is not very meaningful, so be sure to know your externally reachable IP address (here is an example how to get it):

```
ip=$(ip route get 1.1.1.1 | xargs -n1 | sed -ne '/^src$/,+1p' | tail -n1)
```

Then publish both the UDP and TCP port 53 on that address for the docker container:

E.g.:

```
docker run --publish=${ip}::53 --public=${ip}::53/udp
```

Or

```
docker run -p=${ip}::53 -p=${ip}::53/udp
```

And of course, revert all the changes you did to the system resolver.

Comment: running bind on the loopback interface is pretty useless, usually you want to have it available for other hosts. It would be better to bind it to the external interface instead.

Comment: And you need to add `/udp` to the publish address.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Good comments on both counts. Updated the answer.